# Indentation text at beamer

Tags: beamer, indentation

I am trying to indent just text in beamer, but I did not get it. I would like to indent the text at the all document. The problem is that the frame title has been indented and I do not want that. How can I fix it? If anyone knows, I will be very glad.

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.8em,text margin right=1.8em}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
```

The layout that I would like to see:[image]

Comment: Including large blocks of text is a bad way to create a presentation, and one could argue that this is part of beamer's way of incentivizing you not to do that.

Comment: The problem here is that invoking `\setlength{\parindent}{2em}` you will have to "correct" not only the frame title but also some other elements such as blocks. Why do you want first line indentation in a presentation, anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that invoking

```
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
```

you are affecting not only the frame title but also some other elements such as blocks. You can then use `\addtobeamertemplate` to "correct" each element for which you don't want to apply the indentation; my example code below shows this for the `frametitle`, `block begin` and `blobk example begin` templates, but probably you will need to do the same for some other templates.

Why do you want first line indentation in a presentation, in the first place?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\justifying
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.8em,text margin right=1.8em}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\setlength{\parindent}{0em}}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setlength{\parindent}{0em}}{\setlength{\parindent}{2em}}
\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{\setlength{\parindent}{0em}}{\setlength{\parindent}{2em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test title}
\framesubtitle{A test subtitle}
Some test text with some additional information to span more than one line test text with some additional information to span more than one line.
\begin{block}{A test block}
Some test text inside a block with some additional information to span more than one line.
\end{block}
\begin{exampleblock}{A test block}
Some test text inside a block
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! It worked! I just want to make a pattern. That's it.

Comment: And if I don't indent the first line, but keep the rest? Thanks!